# VsCode Intellisense for current file type

Tags: javascript, c#, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I get C# or VB intellisense in JavaScript file.

Intellisense was working great before plugin support. I use to love this editor.

Do I miss something?

[image]

Comment: This is not really a programming question in itself, so you might get burned. By the look of the things, I believe that's Microsoft's ned editor Code. I had the similar issue. Solved it by reinstalling the editor.

Comment: @Transcendental This is not core programming forum anymore. Do you have suggestion to post somewhere else?